# Selenium IDE Dynamic Button

Tags: selenium

I'm trying to make some tests,i'm complete new to selenium,i'm trying to create a test buy the button i'm using is dymanic,i'm using the target this:

```
id=A7486:productForm:listProducts:0:j_idt123
```

but after the application closes,the button is now:

```
id=A7486:productForm:listProducts:0:j_idt119
```

In this page,there is various buttons with the code j_idt   ,so i can't use contains.
Is there a way to click in the correct button?

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the selector that is fix and not generated and from this place go down or up the path